# Is it possible to use the magnet uri scheme in PKGBUILDs?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, bittorrent, makepkg, msys

Is it possible to use resources exchanged with the BitTorrent protocol in `pacman`'s `PKGBUILD`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You just need to specify a magnet uri scheme download agent like [`transmission-makepkg`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/transmission-makepkg) in the `makepkg` configuration file:

```bash
/etc/makepkg.conf
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
DLAGENTS+=('magnet::/usr/bin/transmission-makepkg %u %o')
```

Comment: Did you want to link this package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/transmission-dlagent ?

Comment: @ctx yes thanks!